# How to run current .cpp file in RAD Studio?

Tags: c++, ide, c++builder, rad-studio

When I ran `file1.cpp`, it worked perfect. But now, I want to run `test1.cpp`, but it's not working. There is no option to run the second `.cpp` file.

How can I run `test1.cpp` in RAD Studio?

[image]

Comment: create new console project and either use `#include` or copy/use the code/file as source file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear from your screenshot that `test1.cpp` is not part of the currently loaded `Project1` project.  Only `File1.cpp` is.  You can't just run a standalone `.cpp` file from the IDE.  You have to add the `.cpp` file to a project first (in your case, simply right-click on `Project1.exe` in the [Project Manager](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Project_Manager_(IDE_Tutorial)), choose ["Add"](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Add_to_Project), and select `test1.cpp`), and then you can compile the project into a runnable executable (provided the code is valid, that is).